# PHP for each - return results "live" not when the array is completed

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop, each

I can't remember how I did this before, but there had been a way that I used a while loop and it returned the result after each loop, not after the entire array was looped through.

I am now using for each though, but I assume the same practice should be able to be applied to for each. 
I have a multiple photo uploader that I want the photos to return as soon as each one is finished, not when all of them are done.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking for; but if you want to display the content to the user as it's done, check PHP manual for flush() and ob_flush() : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

Comment: can you put your code here; it will help to provide the well answer what you want

Comment: Flush is exactly what it was, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you searching for [ob_flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) ?

Will output the contents of the output buffer and can be controled in your for each array.